# ruby raised another command is already in progress

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, psql, pg

I would like to enter a large amount of data in my file.
To do this, I am thinking of using postgresql's asynchronous processing to do the query.
The code is as follows.

```
raw_conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

raw_conn.send_query("SELECT id FROM users")
raw_conn.set_single_row_mode
begin
  raw_conn.get_result.stream_each do |f|
    # writing process to file
  end
end

raw_conn.send_query("SELECT id FROM logins")
raw_conn.set_single_row_mode
begin
  raw_conn.get_result.stream_each do |f|
    # writing process to file
  end
end
```

When the second send_query is executed, the following error occurs.

```
 another command is already in progress
```

I had a feeling that the connection pool was the cause, but the documentation did not mention it.
Is there any way to run send_query more than once and get results?

Comment: You can try creating a new connection for the second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Resolved.
I tried to reset the connection before sending a new query, and it worked.

```
begin
  raw_conn.get_result.stream_each do |f|
    # writing process to file
  end
ensure
 raw_conn.reset
end
```